# Как импортировать System.Collections.Generic.IList?

Tags: c#

Обычный non-generic IList я могу подключить так:

```
using IList = System.Collections.IList;
```

Вопрос: как аналогичным способом подключить generic IList?

Comment: чем вас не устраивает ``using System.Collections.Generic;``?

Comment: Подключением всего сразу. К примеру в одном классе я могу использовать как внешнюю библиотеку со своим HashSet, так и System.Collections.Generic. Что-то одно всё-же придётся подключать поэлементно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, в общем виде - никак, только с конкретными уже подставленными типами.

[Откуда я сделал такой вывод (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sf0df423.aspx)